# MacBook Pro will not shut all the way off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When I tried to shut off my MacBookPro, the Apple Insignia, on the outside case, is still illuminated, and the screen is black, but I have the outline of the mouse pointer.  It will not turn back on.  None of the keyboard keys do anything.  It seems to be locked up.  Has anybody experienced this issue, and have a solution to fix?

Answer (score 1):

If you tire of waiting, press and hold the power button.

If you want to run a disk check, reboot to recovery and use Disk Utility. Usually, it's just a stuck process and you won't need to fix things. Test a power off to see if the hang was incidental or if it happens 3 out of 3 attempts.